# Find the missing sequence

Tags: logical-deduction, pattern

[image]

What's the logic behind the patterns and can someone please mention some sources where I can practice such similar problems? Thanks

Comment: Check other puzzles here on site, searching for ‘sequence’ for example. You might like questions like: https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/5588/5840. ( But do yourself a favour and don’t cheat by reading the answers or hints until you are 100% sure - or even better: Have a second person read the answer and verify your answer instead)

Answer (score 5):

I think

> **>>>>**

Explanation

> If we take three adjacent columns(both vertically and horizontally), it contains "six **<**" and "six **>**" in total. So the top column(which is blank with ? mark) should contain "four **>**" in order to fulfill the criteria.
>
>  
> I really don't know where you can get puzzles like this to practice :(

Comment: Was thinking the same. But it sounded kinky.

Comment: Yea, i also think so.. but i don't think there is another logic other than this.

Comment: i agree with this too

Answer (score 0):

Answer:

> **> > > >**

Reason:

> Consider `<` as a left step and `>` as the right. According to me, the object (on which the operations is taking place) should be at the original position after all the operation in a **row** or in a **column**. So, if we put **> > > >** in the place, so this will be fulfilled.

Explanation:

> Consider `<` and `>` cancel outs each other. So in the first row, there are total **6 right** operations and **2 left** operation, so to put it in the original position there are needed **4 left** operations. Similarly in all the individual columns and in all the individual rows.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe it's

> ">>>>",

since I can see

> a left shift rotation in sequences in every row.